# Class has problems serializing

Tags: c#, serialization, propertygrid

Having a problem with serializing this class as a property colleciton, it part of another property collection and is listed there as:

```
`[PropertyTab("AddCellRules"),
    Browsable(true),
    Description("Add Cell Rules"), Category("ColumnProperties"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<CellRules> CellRules { get; set; }`
```

Actual Class:

```
`[Serializable]
public class CellRules
{
     private bool compliment;
     private Color backColor;

    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("BackgroundColor"), Category("CellProperties"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Color BackgroundColor 
    {
        get
        {
            return backColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (compliment)
            {
                ForeColor = SetForeColor(value);
            }
            backColor = value;
        }
    }

    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("ComplimentBackColor"), Category("CellProperties"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public bool ComplimentBackColor {
        get
        {
            return compliment;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                ForeColor = SetForeColor(BackgroundColor);
            }
            compliment = value;
        }
    }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("ForeColor"), Category("CellProperties")]
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("FontType"), Category("CellProperties"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Font FontType { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("FontStyles"), Category("CellProperties"),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public FontStyle FontStyles { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("TriggerOnData"), Category("CellProperties")]
    public bool TriggerOnData { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("DataTrigger"), Category("CellProperties")]
    public String DataTrigger { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedCellProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("TrggerOperator"), Category("CellProperties")]
    public Operator TrggerOperator { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedColumnProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("Pivot"), Category("ColumnProperties")]
    public PivotTypes Pivot { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedColumnProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("InitialPivot"), Category("ColumnProperties")]
    public bool InitialPivot { get; set; }
    [PropertyTab("AddExtendedColumnProperty")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Description("Alignment"), Category("ColumnProperties")]
    public DataGridViewContentAlignment ContentAlignment { get; set; }

    public CellRules()
    {
        Pivot = PivotTypes.none;
        BackgroundColor = Cell_GlobalVars.backgroundColor;
        ForeColor = Cell_GlobalVars.foreColor;
        FontType = Cell_GlobalVars.fontType;
        FontStyles = Cell_GlobalVars.fontStyles;
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    private Color SetForeColor(Color Colors)
    {
        Color result = Color.Black;
        double Brightness = Math.Sqrt(.299 * Math.Pow(Colors.R, 2) + .587 * Math.Pow(Colors.G, 2) + .114 * Math.Pow(Colors.B, 2));
            if (Brightness < 130)
                result = Color.White;
            return result;
    }
}`
```

I did run the serTool and there were no errors, Any Ideas?...

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: c#, sorry about that I assumed it was obivous

Comment: I placed the [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content) on all the members and now it will serialize as a property on the control, however it still won't serialize when its an attribute of a property of a property. Is there some added decorator to make this happen?

Comment: Problem resolved, one needs to apply the result to a private member that is instantiated at the declaration. What I was doing before was instantiating in the constructor using the setter. That will work when not in a nested approach, which is why it worked as a property for the control but not a attribute in the UI Editor...